# Showing Parameters passed to a SP in Reporting Services 2000

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is there a way to put a report into a debugging mode?

My situation is this.  I'm changing the SP of a report to speed it up in a transition to 2005, in fact this is the same one where the funky from was from, and for some reason when I call the SP from SQL it takes 4 seconds.  When the report runs, well its been 20 mins and its still running.  I'm fairly sure that I'm duplicating the passed parameters.

Though since the time difference I'm probably not.  In LogiXML you can enable debugging links and they will allow you to see the parameters passed to an SP and like.  There must be something similar in SSRS.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welp doing even more testing it seems the rendering is where all the time is being taken.

Comment: Did SQL 2000 Reports have an Execution Log or RS_ExecutionLog like 2005 and 2008 do?

Comment: the funky 'from was from', didn't they have a hit with 'walk the dinosaur' ? boom boom akka lakka lakka boom...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to SQL Profiler?

If so you could run a trace and see exactly what is being sent to the server. Also the trace might give you some additional information about why it is taking so long (e.g. is the number of reads hugely more than you would expect - or maybe you will see that the query finishes and then a lot of time gets taken up in the report rendering.)